# App is not 64 bit compliant after adding SF SDK

Tags: mobilesdk, sfdcmobilesdk-android, salesforce-sdk-android

I am getting error in uploading the APK to managed playstore when SF SDK is updated,

I had added the 9.2.1 SDK in android

the error is as below

[image: Please find the error in the image]

Comment: Hey Dinagar, Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange. 
You need to provide more details and elaborate your question a little bit more in the form of steps that you've done so far and the ways by which you tried to accomplish it.

Right now, it is only understandable to those specific people who really understand what you're asking and if they had face the exact same thing. No one else would like to do any research on it and probably skip instead of answering it. 

I'd request you to provide the more details so that you can get help from the community and it could become a good source of help for

Comment: please check the image

Comment: If you get no response here, consider posting your question as an issue here https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Android/issues. There is recent activity there.